# How to make code ready to be made into an executable?

Tags: python, qt, executable, py2exe

I created a pretty large Python project with multiple GUIs. I was thinking of creating an executable from it using `py2exe`, which automatically includes all packages you're using and it formats the files so that imports and everything will run fine.

However, there are lines in my code where I load the UI from a path:

```
self.ui = uic.loadUi('C:/peter/myfolder/stuffs/sub_ui/ManualBalanceUI.ui', self.window)
```

Where `ManualBalanceUI.ui` is the file that Qt Designer creates. I want to write it in a way that it will always open for any user. How should I change that line of code so that it will always be able to load `ManualBalanceUI.ui`, which is located in the `sub_ui` folder in the main package? Is there any way I can change the base path to something like `os.getcwd()`, and then do something like

```
self.ui = uic.loadUi(os.getcwd() + 'sub_ui/ManualBalanceUI.ui', self.window)
```

What would be the best way to approach this problem? Thanks

Comment: Be aware of licence under which py2exe or analogues are released: when you make a solid executable or a directory-based distribution, you in fact statically link to your py-to-exe provider modules.

Comment: What implications does that have for me? Sorry I've never used py2exe before

Comment: The `py2exe` seems to be released under MIT licence which is quite good (you may use https://tldrlegal.com/ for quick reference). Problems arise when you want to use something under GPL-like licence. See this discussion for example http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/179084.

Answer (score 0):

See this discussion [How to make a Python script standalone executable to run without ANY dependency?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5458048).